# How to append data to a empty list in for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, python-requests

> I have 100 URL's in my csv file and I want to know whether those URL's are
>   working or not and for this I imported requests library. When I
>   execute the below code I can see the " status code 200 " for each
>   website when printed. Here when I tried to append the URL's to the
>   empty list the code is printing "This website is not working". How to
>   assign those URL's to empty list?

```
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    url_list = pd.read_csv("/home/user/Desktop/websites.csv")
    urls = url_list['URLS']



    def addhttp():

        url_list=[]
        for url in urls:
            try:
                final_url = 'http://' + url
                response = requests.get(final_url)
                if response.status_code is 200:
                    url_list.append(response.url)

                else:
                    print("This website is not working")
            except:
                pass
        print(url_list)


    print(addhttp())
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you sure that the urls are all ***http://*** ?
2) Could you show us the first lines of your *csv
3) Is it possible that the urls are all not working? Have you checked at least one of them manually?

Comment: Yes, I checked them all are http only

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` and not `is`, as that tests for identity and not value:

```
final_url = 'http://' + url
response = requests.get(final_url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    url_list.append(response.url)
else:
    print("This website is not working")
```

Comment: I tried to replace 'is' with '=' but still it wasn't appending the value to empty list.

Comment: I said `==`, not `=`

Comment: As request library is very slow and it took almost 30 minutes to output the data. My previous code itself working and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

url_list = pd.read_csv("/home/user/Desktop/websites.csv")
and
url_list=[]

use the same variable name

and you use "is" instead of "=="

and you don't return anything at the end of the function

```
url_list = '''
repl.it/@bamamo68/WorrisomeTrivialRectangle-1?1
repl.it/@bamamo68/WorrisomeTrivialRectangle-1?2
repl.it/@bamamo68/WorrisomeTrivialRectangle-1?
'''
urls = url_list.splitlines()

def addhttp(urls):
  url_list2=[]
  for url in urls:
      try:
          final_url = 'http://' + url
          response = requests.get(final_url)
          if response.status_code == 200:
              url_list2.append(response.url)
          else:
              print("This website is not working")
      except:
          pass
  return url_list2


print(addhttp(urls))
```

and this code only work if the urls inside the csv file don't start with "http://" because you add it after in the line with:
final_url = 'http://' + url

Comment: a litle mistake :) @Alxe319

Comment: I have csv file and you have written string.

Comment: @Jainmiah i know but i dont have your csv file you have not publish it so i make the code like that, it should work with your file, you just have to change the begining and test